# Different accuracy results with Keras lstm in R taking into account the same database and parameters

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am using Keras lstm in R to prediction and it works properly, despite the accuracy result vary even with the same database and parameters. I have considered the set.seed and tf$random$set_seed without success. What could I try in addition?

I have tried set.seed and tf$random$set_seed
"relu" activations